# Is it bad practice to create an instance of JFrame inside EDT thread?

Tags: java, swing

I was reading a tutorial about 2D games in Java using `javax.swing`, and in the tutorial they used:

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      JFrame ex = new UtilityTimerEx();
      ex.setVisible(true);
});
```

But the tutorial didn't explain what does `EventQueue.invokeLater(...)` do, so I researched about it, and from my understanding this method is used for running code inside **EDT** which is a thread that should be used only for GUI changes, so shouldn't the initializing of the JFrame instance be written outside `EventQueue.invokeLater(...)`? Wouldn't this be better?

```
JFrame ex = new UtilityTimerEx();
EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      ex.setVisible(true);
});
```

Comment: All access to Swing components, including creating them, should go on the EDT. The example from the tutorial is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No; the EDT should be used for all the GUI work you can muster. Any calculations that have nothing to do with the UI at all (doesn't make, change, or read *ANY* part of the user interface), *those* should be left outside of the EDT.

There are 2 things you must never do in the EDT:

1. Common: Do not ever 'block' - any code that can feasibly cause the CPU to freeze it, so do any networking or any file reading of any sort, or waiting on another thread (possibly by pushing things into a blockingqueue for example), or `Thread.sleep` - all verboten. If you do this, your app will look unresponsive and soon the OS will be asking the end-user if they'd like to close the crashed app. Note that various libraries obviously do this internally and that's just as bad. Do NOT query a database from within the EDT; that query goes out via networking and needs to wait for an answer: Both big nonos in the EDT. Farm it out to another thread, and once the DB query is done, relay the info back, in the form of changing UI widgets, by using `EventQueue.invokeLater`, because modifying the UI from outside the EDT is also a big nono.
2. Uncommon: Jobs that take a really long time. Literally keeping the CPU busy without pausing. You'd need to be, I dunno, mining for bitcoin or encoding video or whatnot. Once it grows to a job that is well known to really take noticably long, yeah, put that in a thread.

NB: The more modern `SwingWorker` class can be quite useful, it's less tricky to use than rolling your own threads and not forgetting to enclose all UI-modifying code in an `invokeLater`.

Comment: Did you mean to say "Yes"? The question is if it's a bad practice.

Comment: No, it's not bad practice at all. You're creating GUI things, it's fine to do this in the EDT; in many cases, it is mandatory to do it there. The creation of that frame neither blocks, nor is it clearly excessively CPU intensive.